# Vue Router save scroll position on a route and go back to that position when navigating back?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using Vue Router and scrollBehavior and each route still loads a the top of the page (0,0), rather than remembering my scroll position. Thoughts on what I'm missing?

Here's my router code:

```
const scrollBehavior = (to, from, savedPosition) => {
  if (savedPosition) {
    return savedPosition;
  } else {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  }
};
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
  scrollBehavior,
});
```

Comment: Have you checked for `history.pushState` support in the browser you are testing? Also, log the `savedPosition` because no scrolling will happen if the values are falsy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you checked for `history.pushState` support in the browser you are testing? Also, log the `savedPosition` because no scrolling will happen if the values are falsy. When creating the router instance, you can provide the `scrollBehavior` function as given,

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [...],
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
      return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
})
```

The `scrollBehavior` function receives the to and from route objects. The third argument, `savedPosition`, is only available if this is a `popstate` navigation (triggered by the browser's back/forward buttons).

The function can return a scroll position object. The object could be in the form of:

```js
{ x: number, y: number }
//or
{ selector: string, offset? : { x: number, y: number }} //offset only supported in 2.6.0+
```

If a falsy value or an empty object is returned, no scrolling will happen.

> **Note: this feature only works if the browser supports `history.pushState`**

If you want, You can store the current scroll offset before navigating. Here is how you can do it.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
let scrollOffset = {x: container.scrollTop, y: container.scrollLeft}
```

Now, store the `scrollOffset` before routing, when the `savedPosition` is falsy, You can use this object.

Comment: I'm using the latest Chrome so I assume it supports `history.pushState`. The popstate might be the issue because I'm using custom buttons in the app with router.push in some cases and router.go(n) in others. Any way to get router.push to respect popstate?

Comment: router.push will not work, the savedPoition will only contain offset values if the navigated through the browser back/forward. You can figure out the implementation from here https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/scroll-behavior/app.js

Comment: Thank you kindly. That's what I was thinking. Only think in your answer is x = scrollLeft and y = scrollTop (I think) :)

Comment: How would I store the scrollOffset before routing? In the View object? Or the route? How? Could someone give an example?

Comment: It's `{ top: 0, left: 0 }`, not x and y anymore in the new Vue-Router.

Answer (score 2):

```
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (to.hash) {
          return resolve({ selector: to.hash });
        } else if (savedPosition) {
          return resolve(savedPosition);
        } else {
          resolve(document.getElementById("app").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" }));
        }
      }, 1200);
    });
   
  },
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).